# Why does :only-of-type require a different HTML tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**Problem**: I have a grid made up of cards. Not all cards are equal width. Some cards are 1/4 and other cards are 3/4 width. The grid must always come out to a whole number. Occasionally the 3/4 width cards are side by side.

**Solution**: Inspired by CSS quantity queries I want to change the 3/4 cards width to be 1/2 when there is more than 1 in a row. Referencing [this article from A List Part](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css#snippet3), I found the proper pseudo class *:only-of-type* to achieve this.

However, it seems that when all the html tags are the same the *:only-of-type* pseudo selector doesn't behave how you think it should.

[Code pen example](http://codepen.io/Cuberic/pen/MbRKWZ)

```css
// The money style
.pinned:not(:only-of-type) {
  width: 50%;
}
// EXTRA STUFF //
/* Basic Card */
.panel {
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
/* Featured Card */
.pinned {
  .panel {
    border-color: rgb(51, 122, 183);
    background-color: rgb(51, 122, 183);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<article class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Same HTML Tag</h2>
  <section class="row">
    <div class="pinned col-xs-9">
      <div class="panel">Featured Card</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="panel">Basic Card</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="panel">Basic Card</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
<article class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Differnt HTML Tags</h2>
  <section class="row">
    <aside class="pinned col-xs-9">
      <div class="panel">Featured Card</div>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="panel">Basic Card</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
```

It accepts the class name as a target, but the browser required the HTML tags to be different. Is this the intended behavior? Are there other pseudo selectors more dependent on the markup more than the class names?

Comment: *However, it seems that when all the html tags are the same the `:only-of-type` pseudo selector doesn't behave how you think it should.* .. It sounds like you're forgetting that `:not()` is in the mix. This gives you the opposite of standard behavior.

Comment: Most probably you thought `:only-of-type` behaved like `:only-of-match`. No, "type" in `:only-of-type` refers to the element type, given by the HTML tag

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working fine.

This is your selector and declaration:

```
.pinned:not(:only-of-type) {
   width: 50%;
}
```

In plain English:

- The `:only-of-type` pseudo-class selects elements that have no siblings of the same element type.
- But you want the opposite of this (**`:not()`**)
- Therefore, the selector is targeting the element with class `.pinned` that has siblings of the same element type.

In your first example, a `div` has the `.pinned` class. This `div` has two sibling divs. This is a match. The element gets the `width: 50%`.

```
<section class="row">
   <div class="pinned col-xs-9">
      <div class="panel">Featured Card</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
       <div class="panel">Basic Card</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
       <div class="panel">Basic Card</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

In your second example, an `aside` element has the `.pinned` class. There are no other `aside` siblings (it's an `:only-of-type`). There is no match. The `width: 50%` is ignored.

```
<section class="row">
   <aside class="pinned col-xs-9">
     <div class="panel">Featured Card</div>
   </aside>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
     <div class="panel">Basic Card</div>
   </div>
</section>
```